# Large white space appearing between Text and Line of Picker after adding inside <AbsoluteLayout>

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

Adding below Picker inside StackLayout works fine.

```
<Picker HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Title="Select Category" 
                                    x:Name="categorypicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}" />
```

Now, I need to add loaders on the right side of these pickers,so encapsulated `<Picker>` and `<ActivityIndicator>` inside an `<AbsoluteLayout>` like this:

```
<AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                <Picker AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   Title="Select Category" 
                                    x:Name="categorypicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}" />
                                <ActivityIndicator AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,40,1" Scale="0.6"
                                                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,HeightProportional"
                                                   IsRunning="{Binding ShowCategoryLoader}" />
                        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Everything else seems to be working fine, but now a large space is showing between text and line in picker.
Tried with HeightRequest in Picker, ActivityIndicator & AbsoluteLayout.But nothing seems to work.

After:   [image]

**Note:** It would be great ,if it can be fixed with only XAML and not programmatically code behind or custom picker

Comment: remove PositionProportional flag

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri I've set 40 as constant value for width, but everything else is proportional.So,i think PositionProportional is required there

Comment: is the Scale also so intended ?

Comment: @MuhannadFakhouri yes,as in Android,activityindicators are too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to let the **ActivityIndicator**  in the right of **Picker** ,you can use **Grid** instead of **AbsoluteLayout** .

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition  Height="50"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition  Width="0.3*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition  Width="0.4*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition  Width="0.3*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Picker Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   Title="Select Category"  x:Name="categorypicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Title}" />
  <ActivityIndicator Grid.Column="0"  IsRunning="True" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: ActivityIndicator should be ON the picker, not outside of picker.So,this will not work.
That's why used <AbsoluteLayout>

Comment: It worked but still i can't add it in my app as, i can't give Height=50, as apps can be used by old age persons, so font will be large and text cuts off from top in that case.
Do you better option for that ?

Comment: You can set the height as `Auto` and set the font and size of picker and  ActivityIndicator

Comment: Yup,tried that , but with Height="Auto" , white space is again showing

Comment: You need to set the Height request of picker and ActivityIndicator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202651/discussion-between-bhavya-joshi-and-lucas-zhang-msft).

Comment: Hey lucas, can you please explain how/why grid layout didn't disturb the picker spacing unlike of absolutelayout